# Get Attribute of hidden (display:none) html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the href attribute of a hidden element e.g.

```
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="inline1" style="width:640px; height: 363px; overflow:hidden;">
<a class="a.player" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 360px; " href="http://myvideo.mp4"></a>
</div>
</div>

var videolink = $('a.player').attr('href');

alert (videolink);
```

This will give an undefined value, any help would be great.

Comment: As Daniel has stated your class name shouldn't contain .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class name is flawed.

You should just name it `player` and then select it with `a.player`.

Comment: kinda embaracing anyway that fixed it

Comment: @Psylant - dont worry about it. mistakes are the best way to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('.a.player').attr('href');
```

or change classname to:

```
player
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<a class="player">
```

istead of

```
<a class="a.player">
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to specify the class name as `class=a.player` it should be `class="player"`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fQVLj/9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="inline1" style="width:640px; height: 363px; overflow:hidden;">
<a id="myHref" class="aplayer" style="display: block; width: 640px; height: 360px; " href="http://myvideo.mp4"></a>
</div>
</div>

var videolink = $('.aplayer').attr('href');
//var videolink = $('#myHref').attr('href');
alert (videolink);
```

Fiddle link [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FSDR4/)